# Selecting rows with a certain weekday in DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a DataFrame with time index like:

```
df.index = [2013-09-09 06:23:18, 2013-09-10 07:09:05, ..., 2014-02-02 06:04:04]
```

How could I choose rows in certain weekday, like Monday? Then I won't have the rows in other weekdays. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the weekday by `df.index.weekday`, note that `Monday = 0` and `Sunday = 6`

To select the rows on Monday, you can do

```
df = df[df.index.weekday==0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here "Date" is the column name.
Creating new column "weekday"

```
df["weekday"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.dayofweek
```

From this column you can select any weekday from dataframe

```
df.loc[df["weekday"] ==6]
```

Here 6 denotes "Sunday"

Comment: This is not correct, according to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html), `dayofweek` (as well as `weekday`) returns "the day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6"!