# Dataframe Row Selection by Weekday of Index in Python

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe, weekday

I am trying to select every Friday in a dataframe of daily stock price closes.  I read and tried the suggestion in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774089/selecting-rows-with-a-certain-weekday-in-dataframe-in-python), specifically:

```
Fridays = df[df.index.weekday == 4] #Fridays
```

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I believe the issue is that Python does not recognize the strings in the index as dates, but I can't figure out why.  The DataFrame looks like this:

```
1993-04-08    3387.83
1993-04-12    3420.79
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
```